# LUKS on LVM – how to manage suspend/resume on external hdd?

Tags: lvm, luks, external-hdd

I've just set up LUKS on top of LVM on my external hard drive. However, when I leave the hdd idle for an hour, I am getting I/O errors in dmesg when the drive spins up again:

```
[170969.546887] usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[170969.547330] scsi host2: usb-storage 2-1.4:1.0
[170970.574026] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Elements 25A3    1031 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[170970.576113] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[170971.585872] ................ready
[170986.787020] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Very big device. Trying to use READ CAPACITY(16).
[170986.787243] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 27344699392 512-byte logical blocks: (14.0 TB/12.7 TiB)
[170986.787250] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] 4096-byte physical blocks
[170986.787647] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[170986.787654] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 47 00 10 08
[170986.788024] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[170986.788027] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[170986.852342]  sdc: sdc1
[170986.852831] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
[171028.865016] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem a01e267a-b9ac-4b68-9f6d-1191504bd141 r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[171151.811261]  sdb:
[171151.819727]  sdb:
[171157.798163]  sdb: sdb1
[171269.797792]  sdb:
[171274.365828]  sdb: sdb1
[171689.034275] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[171689.034831] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[171689.035315] EXT4-fs (dm-3): VFS: Can't find ext4 filesystem
[171689.035853] FAT-fs (dm-3): invalid media value (0xe0)
[171689.035856] FAT-fs (dm-3): Can't find a valid FAT filesystem
[171796.570016] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem 87a2af07-31cb-48ac-ab39-27df18e3cdf7 r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[171806.585146] EXT4-fs (dm-3): unmounting filesystem 87a2af07-31cb-48ac-ab39-27df18e3cdf7.
[171820.969008] EXT4-fs (dm-1): unmounting filesystem a01e267a-b9ac-4b68-9f6d-1191504bd141.
[171834.824288] EXT4-fs (dm-1): mounted filesystem a01e267a-b9ac-4b68-9f6d-1191504bd141 r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[171883.325483] EXT4-fs (dm-3): mounted filesystem 87a2af07-31cb-48ac-ab39-27df18e3cdf7 r/w with ordered data mode. Quota mode: none.
[176366.299170] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[176366.318571] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[176366.318582] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 46 0c a0 00 00 00 02 00 00 00
[176366.318585] I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1175232512 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 5 prio class 2
[176483.369356] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[176483.388842] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[176483.388858] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 00 48 2c 9e 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
[176483.388879] I/O error, dev sdc, sector 1210883584 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 2
[223800.442702] usb 2-1.4: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[223800.461991] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[223800.462002] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(16) 88 00 00 00 00 02 d6 98 81 00 00 00 01 00 00 00
[223800.462005] I/O error, dev sdc, sector 12190253312 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 3 prio class 2
```

This is certainly an issue for me as this external hdd is attached to a server and I often leave the hdd for hours without accessing its data.

The [Arch Linux Wiki has got an article about that](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/LVM#Suspend/resume_with_LVM_and_removable_media), however, there is also a [comment](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Talk:LVM#LVM_on_removable_media) that the Wiki's solution wouldn't work for more complex setups like LUKS on LVM.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: Try to break.down the problem: Do not mount the filesystem, and just leave the disk alone for a while. Then try to wake-up the disk (e.g. using ``fdisk -l`), then try to mount. Next try the same without using `fdisk` to wake up the disk. If fdisk already failed, it's most likely a power-management issue with USB.